# Matching 2 strings against each other in C?

Tags: c, string, sockets, char, webserver

For some reason it is never entering this loop, even though wordSave is exactly the same string as cacheList[0].fileName

```
if (fileNameInCache(wordSave) != -1)
{
    printf("File found in cache.\n");
    n = write(sock, cacheList[fileNameInCache(wordSave)].fileContent, 4096);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the method for checking the cache for the filename:

```
int fileNameInCache(char* name)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++)
    {
        if (cacheList[i].fileName == name)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

cacheList is an array of structs where fileName is a char* as well.

Any idea why it never enters this loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strcmp(chacheList[i].fileName, name) == 0)
{
    //the strings are "equal"
    return i;
}
```

Also add an `#include <string.h>` to the top of your file.

[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) reference.

Reading up on cstrings is a great idea as well! They are interpreted as `char*`s, basically pointers to the first character of a "string," with sequentially stored other characters up until a null character (`'\0'`) indicates the string is over.

[This](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html) is also a great resource for what you are working with!

Comment: Worked great after i allocated memory for the name! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C you are working with memory pointers to strings. Your `cacheList[i].fileName` is a different pointer than your `name` variable. When you do `cacheList[i].fileName == name` you actually compare the addresses of your strings and not the content of your strings. Instead you should use `strcmp(chacheList[i].fileName, name)` to compare strings in C. You can find more information here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Also, don't forget to `#include <string.h>`